# Deploying a VMSS and injecting secrets

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am wondering if there is any straightforward way of injecting files/secrets into the vms of a scaleset, either as you perform the (ARM) deployment or change the image.

This would be application-level passwords, certificates, and so on, that we would not want to be stored on the images.

I am using the linux custum script extension for the entrypoint script, and realize that it's possible to inject some secrets as parameters to that script. I assume this would not work with certificates however (too big/long), and it would not be very future-proof as we would need to redeploy the template (and rewrite the entrypoint script) whenever we want to add or remove a secret.

Answer (score 0):

Windows based VMSS can get certificates from the KV directly during deployment, but linux ones cannot do that. Also, there is a customData property which allows you to pass in whatever you want (i think its limited to 64kb base64 encoded data), but that is not really flexible as well.

One way of solving this - write an init script that would use Managed Service Identity to get secrets from the Key Vault, this way you get several advantages:

1. You dont store secrets in the templates\vm configuration
2. You can update the secret and all the VMSS will get new version on the next deployment
3. You dont have to edit the init script unless secret names changed or new secrets got introduced.